# Return value of std::condition_variable::wait_until

Tags: c++, std

According to [C++ doc](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/wait_until/) for `std::condition_variable::wait_until`:

> The predicate version (2) returns pred(), regardless of whether the timeout was triggered (although it can only be false if triggered).

My question is: why it states that the return can only be false if timeout is triggered, given the fact that the predicate value can change to `true` while `wait_until` is blocked? Am I missing something?

Comment: cplusplus is not a good online source. You should prefer [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until).

Comment: Indeed, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until) states that the return is `false if the predicate pred still evaluates to false after the timeout_time timeout expired, otherwise true. [...]`

Comment: The predicate is evaluated only on wake. If the predicate value changes to `true` but the condition variable is not woken, then that `true` value is never observed. Better wording would be "returns the last evaluated value of `pred()`".

Comment: @RaymondChen Sou you say that in the case of timeout, it is not the current value of the predicate that is returned?

Comment: It can never be the metaphysically current value, because that value can change between the `return;` statement at the end of `wait_until` and the first statement of the caller.

Comment: @RaymondChen Let me rephrase: is the predicate re-evaluated on timeout? From [cppreferance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until), where ii says _2) Equivalent to_, it follows that it does.

Comment: @Murukan cppreference is correct, it is re-evaluated. you can even check e.g. gcc [source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/4739344d36e6d24764cbedde44a3fff6edc70f6c/libstdc++-v3/include/std/condition_variable#L151)

Comment: @dewaffled Even better, check [the spec](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.condition.condvar#30). The predicated is evaluated one last time on timeout.